# If checkbox checked set values

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem as follows. if cell A6 is checked then cell G6 will be set to 0.5 and the rest is 0 and i want to automatic do that [This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4gTD.png)
And this is my code . I really appreciate that

```
function setvalues() {   
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];   
  if (sheet.getRange('A6').isChecked() === 'TRUE') {
     sheet.getRange('I6').setValue(0.5);   
  } else {
     sheet.getRange('G6').setValue(0);    
  } 
}
```

Comment: `if cell A6 is checked then cell G6 will be set to 0.5 and the rest is 0` this doesn't match the code you showed. In the code you showed (disregarding that you're comparing a boolean to a string - see [Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666010)), if the checkbox is checked, `G6` will be set to `0` and `I6` will be set to `0.5`, and no other cell will be changed. Is this what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setvalues() {   
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];   
  if (sheet.getRange('A6').isChecked()) {
     sheet.getRange('I6').setValue(0.5);   
  } else {
     sheet.getRange('G6').setValue(0);    
  } 
}
```

[Range.isChecked() returns a boolean](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isChecked())